# Restrict specific String to store in DB

Tags: java, string, hibernate

I am working on an issue using Java where i have to restrict specific string to store in DB.Example : "NAM" or "nam"

if some data "Vietnam" (Contains "nam") is coming to store in any column, i have to restrict and give some kind of error or notification.

This is easy if we are working one object but if there are multiple tables in the DB and we need to check each and every column data before storing that is painful. i am looking for some generic code that can work on any object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Hibernate's check annotations:

```
@Entity
@Check(constraints = "col1 <> 'Vietnam' AND col2 <> 'Vietnam'")
public class YourEntity {
    @Column(name = "col1")
    private String col1;

    @Column(name = "col2")
    private String col2;

    ...
}
```

Hibernate should then throw an exception should any entity arrive with a field having the value `Vietnam`.

If you can't use Hibernate check annotations, a general solution which might work here on the database level would be a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT cntry_cnstr CHECK (col1 <> 'Vietnam' AND col2 <> 'Vietnam' AND ...);
```

Attempting to insert a new record where a column contains `Vietnam`, or attempting to update an existing record's column to `Vietnam` would then trigger an exception which you could handle in Java.